# The file "product856_n.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: php, laravel

I want to save multiple categories in products.
products name  image same but category different

- `CateogryID   2 = Mobile`
- `CategoryID   3 = Apple`

```
id Productname  CateoryID   image
----------------------------------------
1  Iphone X     2           filename.jpg
2  Iphone X     3           filename.jpg
```

```
 public function productsave(Request $request){

    foreach($request->Product_catid as $procat){
        $productobj = new products;
        $productobj->productname = $request->input('productname');
        $productobj->categoryid = $procat;
        $productobj->code = $request->input('code');
        $productobj->buyrate = $request->input('buyrate');
        $productobj->sellrate = $request->input('sellrate');

        if($request->hasfile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('uploads/products/', $filename);
            $productobj->image = $filename;
        }else{
            return $request;
            $productobj->image ='';
        }

        $productobj->save();
    }

    return redirect('/products')->with('productobj', $productobj);

}
```

Comment: why would you return $request; ?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using your method to generate a unique name:

```
$file->storeAs(
    'uploads/products', $filename
);
```

If you just want Laravel to handle generating a unique filename:

```
$file->store('uploads/products');
```

Comment: file saved  but image not uploaded in 'uploadsproducts'